# Visual Studio: how to generate debug symbols for Xamarin Android apps

Tags: xamarin.android, debug-symbols, visual-studio-app-center

I have a Xamarin.Forms app, created using Visual Studio, which includes Android and iOS projects.

The app is deployed via App Center, which supports crash logging, but this feature requires upload of the app's debug symbols.

The App Center documentation includes detailed information about how to [locate and upload debug symbols for iOS projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/diagnostics/ios-symbolication), but there is no equivalent documentation for Android projects. I have also been unable to find this documentation online, either from Xamarin or elsewhere.

Can anyone please point me to a resource that explains Xamarin.Android debug symbolication (or tell me the procedure)?

Comment: Following, as we are in the same boat, today in 2023.

Answer (score 1):

I got the symbol files from: "...{Project}.Android\obj\Debug\130\app_shared_libraries" (there should be a "libxamarin-app" inside) and then zipped the whole folder for one of the architectures (for example, arm64-v8a). You should not change the name or folder structure or Play Console will not accept it.